C++ Tensorflow Lite, getting undefined reference errors on multiple instances while building via CMake
I am trying to setup the C++ API for tensorflow lite. I was following this official minimal example
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow_src

mkdir minimal_build
cd minimal_build
cmake ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal

Everything works fine till here (albeit with multiple deprecation warnings).
However upon running this
cmake --build . -j

I get the following undefined reference errors
/usr/bin/ld: tensorflow-lite/libtensorflow-lite.a(register.cc.o): in function `tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver::BuiltinOpResolver()':
register.cc:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_ABS()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x2b3): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_HARD_SWISH()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x2cd): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_RELU()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_RELU_N1_TO_1()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x307): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_RELU_0_TO_1()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_RELU6()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x341): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_TANH()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x361): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_LOGISTIC()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x381): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_AVERAGE_POOL_2D()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x3a1): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_MAX_POOL_2D()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_L2_POOL_2D()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x3db): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_CONV_2D()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x3fb): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x41b): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_SVDF()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_RNN()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x45b): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_BIDIRECTIONAL_SEQUENCE_RNN()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x47b): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_UNIDIRECTIONAL_SEQUENCE_RNN()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x49b): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_EMBEDDING_LOOKUP()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x4bb): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_EMBEDDING_LOOKUP_SPARSE()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x4d5): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_FULLY_CONNECTED()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x4f5): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_LSH_PROJECTION()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x50f): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_HASHTABLE_LOOKUP()'
/usr/bin/ld: register.cc:(.text+0x529): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::Register_SOFTMAX()'
....

There are hundreds more of these errors. I have no idea how to resolve this since I was just following the documentation as it is and since it is on the official repository I expect it to work properly.
What is odd though is this (this)[https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#step_5_build_tensorflow_lite] article gets tflite to build correctly sometimes but it just provides a static library which according to the article cannot be used and instead cmake is required which then links to the above broken process. And that sometimes is important because otherwise it would throw an error after reaching 100%
[100%] Built target microkernels-all
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1374: CMakeFiles/tensorflow-lite.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2

Is there a way to fix this or install tflite c++ correct because I have spent 7 hours on this and nothing seems to work.
My systems details: Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64

worksforme. wipe your build directory, re-cmake, and build without the -j flag. edit your post to include the entirety of the first error.

I got it working using bazel after spending 3-4 hours more. Thanks though, it was probably a system issue
